# Setup, runTests and teardown fails at Batman.TestCase

Tags: testing, batman.js

I am trying to get [batman testing](http://batmanjs.org/docs/testing.html) up and running. Qunit and tests runs fine, but when i use the example:

```
class SimpleTest extends Batman.TestCase
  @test 'A simple test', ->
    @assert true

test = new SimpleTest
test.runTests()
```

I get the following messages when i browse to localhost:3000/qunit:

> 1. Setup failed on A simple test: undefined is not a function
> 2. Died on test #2     at Test.Batman.TestCase.TestCase.Test.Test.run (localhost:3000/assets/extras/testing/test_case.js?body=1:20:22)
>      at SimpleTest.Batman.TestCase.TestCase.runTests (localhost:3000/assets/extras/testing/test_case.js?body=1:51:28)
>      at localhost:3000/assets/simple_test.js?body=1:24:8
>      at localhost:3000/assets/simple_test.js?body=1:26:4: undefined is not a function
> 3. Teardown failed on A simple test: undefined is not a function

In the test_helper.coffee, I manually included the project, sinon and the four test case source files from the github source code [found here](https://github.com/batmanjs/batman/tree/master/src/extras/testing), including test_case.coffee.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how those `.coffee` source files are loaded, it's possible that they don't have their dependencies loaded first.

You could try this:

- Download the 0.16 release from http://batmanjs.org/download.html
- Use precompiled `batman.testing.js` from the release
- Make sure QUnit loads `batman.js` first, then `batman.testing.js`. (`Batman.Object` must be defined before you load `Batman.TestCase`.)

Does that help?